# Matlab data type specification

Tags: matlab, types, casting

I have a problem with data type in MATLAB. It's a simple code of converting binary to decimal. For my further task, those should be integer 64 bit. How can I do it?

This code converts those value into double. And, type casting isn't helpful; for example, for the first value, sum is `4.0265e+09` but after casting via `Y = typecast(sum, 'int64');` it generates `4750734656922451968` which is not correct value.

**example.png**:

[image]

```
I = imread('example.png');
level = graythresh(I);
img = im2bw(I,level);

sz=size(img);
for i=1:sz(1)
    sum=0;
    p=1;
    for j=sz(2):-1:1
        sum=sum+img(i,j)*p;
        p=p*2;
    end
    disp(sum);
end
```

Comment: Don't use `sum` as the name of your variable; that's a built-in MATLAB function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`cast`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cast.html) instead of [`typecast`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html)

```
>> s = 4.0265e+09;
>> cast(s, 'int64')
ans =
    4026500000
```

[`typecast`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) converts data without altering the underlying `byte` values whereas [`cast`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cast.html) converts data and attempts to keep the same value. [`typecast`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) as you have found can change the value of data as it does not alter the underlying `byte` values. [`typecast`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) simply changes the `type` that MATLAB uses to interpret the underlying `byte` values.

Alternatively you could simply use [`int64`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/int64.html)

```
>> int64(s)
ans =
    4026500000
```

to convert data whilst attempting to keep the same value.

---

**Aside:** [`sum`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) is a built-in MATLAB function. It is not recommended that you call a variable [`sum`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) as you will overwrite the built-in MATLAB function.

Comment: Good job describing the different functions. I'd give you +2 if possible for mentioning not overwriting built-ins!

Comment: @Adriaan Thanks. I wasn't sure my explanation of the differences between `typecast` and `cast` was clear enough. I'm still not!

Comment: I never ever use them, I just use `uint64` etc for datatype conversion. I'll read the docs and get back to you about that; docs: "typecast is different from the MATLAB® cast function in that it does not alter the input data. typecast always returns the same number of bytes in the output Y as were in the input X. For example, casting the 16-bit integer 1000 to uint8 with typecast returns the full 16 bits in two 8-bit segments (3 and 232) thus keeping its original value (3*256 + 232 = 1000). The cast function, on the other hand, truncates the input value to 255."

Comment: @Adriaan I'm the exact same, its just simpler that way.

Comment: What's the problem I actually don't know. Nothing changed!

    int64(addt);
     disp(class(addt));

This generates double.

Comment: @Emtiaj You haven't assigned `addt` to `int64(addt);` so it still represents the `double` value. Use `addt = int64(addt); disp(class(addt));`.